# How to add more desktop backgrounds to the default Plants group?

Tags: macos, mac, desktop-customization

I have some additional plants pictures. I love the "Auto change background feature" of Mac OS X. I use "plants" and "change background every minute".

How can I add more pictures in plants or any other of Apple's groups for backgrounds?

[image: Backgrounds]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the [+] button at the bottom of the list:

[image]

Then you can choose your own folder of pictures to cycle through.

If you want to include the default Plants photos, they are stored at `/Library/Desktop Pictures/Plants`. You could add photos to this folder but I don't really recommend it.

[image]

Comment: Yep ! That worked for me. Great !